# Nginx Configuration with port

Tags: nginx, port, hosting, mern, vps

My Application is hosted on port 3000 and i havent yet connected the domain pointing to ip
I have configured nginx accordingly but these configurations are only applying on my ip like http://ip  not on my port http://ip:3000 , how to i add that port on vps manually?

I tried to add it manually in etc/services file as myapp 3000/tcp but it didn't caused any difference
How do i solve this problem. My Nginx configuration are:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 195.35.22.87;
    root /root/ADMIN/build;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # ... other configurations ...
}
```